# magento 2 what is quote_shipping_rate table

Tags: magento2

What is `quote_shipping_rate` table and how we can add item?

---

I know by `getShippingRatesCollection` i can get the collection of saved rate into the table but I can not find how Magento or another Module add an item into this table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`quote_shipping_rate` table stores the shipping information that has been associated with the quote and address.
Entries in this table are added/updated when you add/update shipping method during the checkout process.
**UPDATE**
Though, I am not 100% sure but it is method `saveAddressInformation` in file/class `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php` which is responsible for updating the table.

Comment: yeah i know but which class set item into this table ?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Magento stores the selected shipping method details in `quote_shipping_rate` with the foreign key of `address_id` from the quote.

Magento adding/updating the entry in a table from the [`importShippingRate()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address/Rate.php#L87) method [`Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address/Rate.php#L38) class and generally it update/add entry while calling `collectShippingRates()` method from the [`Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address.php#L100)

**EDIT**

**You can see new entry if your quote is fresh otherwise you will see only changes in `rate_id`. If you want to see new entry then please check with fresh quote/new customer/or placed order with current quote and check**

*If you want to watch the entry in the `quote_shipping_rate` please open your database (Ex. phpMyAdmin) and your Magento 2 frontend. On the Magento 2 frontend add the product into the cart and go to the checkout page and select the shipping method and check `quote_shipping_rate` method you will see the new entry with your selected shipping method.*

Comment: i change my cart to use magento api and i check as you tell me . i see result on database is fixed just rate id has been changed . so i do not know how is help me to find where magento add items

Comment: Yes, because your current quote is already active that's why it update the entry. If you want to see new entry then please check with new customer or with fresh quote you will see new entry. @ghdarvishani

Comment: Check my edit :) @ghdarvishani

Comment: you are right Mr Shah . i found if some rate are available then magento put it on database . this is part of my code that i think saved the rates https://paste.ubuntu.ir/psqv . in my code rate are get before they saved . how it can impossible ?

Comment: I think it is a different question than this one I gave the answer for your current question so If you have a new question please shoot new question.